# How do I open VS code from conda terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, anaconda

Very trivial question.

I'm trying to launch VS Code from an anaconda environment terminal.
When I'm opening Jupyter notebook I simply type `$jupyter notebook`, or for spyder `$spyder`.

I've tried:

```
$code . 
$vscode
$VScode
$vs code 
$VS code
```

all returning

```
bash: code: command not found
```

VS code is installed in the environment and I can launch from the icon. My question is how do I launch from the terminal?

Comment: This might be useful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: Have you added the bin folder of the VSCode to the system environment variables? If you did, 'where code'(on cmd) command should display the path of 'code' command. Otherwise, you need to add it to the system environment variables, then the 'code' command should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to install VS Code using the OS package manager so that the shell as well as your conda environment can detect the command `code .` whenever it is run.

You can then use

`conda activate <virtual_env_name>`

to make the VS Code terminal run on that virtual environment